# Google App Engine dev app server does not display detailed error message

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When developing on Google App Engine dev app server locally (python) and encounter an error, the browser will just show something like the following:

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8080/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Is there a configuration to display the detailed error message?

Comment: Open up the 'Logs' window found on the GAE launcher.

Answer (score 7):

You can use commandline and start dev server with --debug to get verbose debug messages. Here are the docs:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Command_Line_Arguments

You can also add logging to your app to capture the info:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Logging

Comment: Any way when running the local server we will get quite detailed error messages in the console itself .

Comment: @GautamK If by "the console itself", you mean the browser window, that's entirely up to your app and what it chooses to return when it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks, the provided dev server method works.  However, I am just wondering why it use to work when setting the debug to True as in the following code:
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                              debug=True)
In the old GAE SDK Python 2.5 using webapp, the webapp will print stack traces to the browser output if there's an error.  In the new GAE SDK with support for Python 2.7 and webapp2, setting debug=True should work as well but it is not sending error to the browser.

Comment: Can you post your code? Here are the docs on the webapp2: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#debug-flag

Comment: I was following the code from the Getting Started page http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

Comment: I have the same issue. GAE SDK launched in the default way using Google App Engine Launcher under python 2.5 would show stack trace in the browser while the under version 2.7 the browser only shows 500. The stack trace is available in the log but do not understand why this is changed. It would be convenient to have it in the browser.

Comment: This `--debug` option seems to have disappeared, and I can't find any other option that has the effect of displaying stacktraces. Alex Cory's answer works for me, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did and it's working so far.

In your main app file.

```
...
import logging
...

app = Flask(__name__)
...

@app.before_request
def enable_local_error_handling():
    app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 1):

The --debug option no longer exists, but try starting with --dev_appserver_log_level debug, eg:

```
dev_appserver.py $PWD --dev_appserver_log_level debug
```